# How can I branch my project to make sure I can get back to the original version?

Tags: git, git-branch

I will be doing a total overhaul of a website. I already have them under version control with git but I'm still pretty new with git and this is an important client. There are so many git methods I want to make sure I use the right one.

What I would like to do is take my current master and copy it to a branch and then all new changes will be still updated on the master. If for some reason I need to revert to the old version I can call back that branch where I forked.

I've looked at a ton of examples but I would like someone to recommend the best method in their opinion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ git branch original_master
```

That will create a new branch called original_master, branched from the current commit.  You can continue working on the master branch, or you can create as many new ones as you like, merging back into master as you like.

If you ever need to go back to the original code, simply:

```
$ git checkout original_master
```

And you'll be right back from where you started.  So long as you don't commit or merge to the `original_master` branch, it'll stay exactly as you created it.

Answer (score 4):

You don't even need to create a branch - Since you just want to mark a place in the history just use a tag.

**Editied following comments**

For example: say you want to mark the current HEAD as `original` you could tag it with:

```
git tag original
```

`original` is now a shorthand way of referring to that particular. And you can always get back to it by creating a new branch:

```
git checkout -b a_branch original
```

which creates a branch called `a_branch` based on `original`

I wrote about the [tag object](http://365git.tumblr.com/post/497500602/git-objects-the-tag) previously, and also about [signing git tags](http://365git.tumblr.com/post/2796779828/signing-a-git-tag)

Comment: Your answer would be more complete if you would add the relevant commands to make a tag, and to go back to a tag.

Comment: This is a better answer than creating a new branch. Release versions are a easier to manage with tags. Versions under current development are best managed with branches.

Comment: +1 also note that using a branch explicitly invites the risk that someones alters it, whereas with a tag, it can't be done (except for filter-branch --tag-name-filter, but that probably won't even work for signed tags)